# Xubuntu: fstab mount to /media/* is not shown on desktop

Tags: mount, xubuntu, xfce, fstab

I have recently changed from Ubuntu to Xubuntu and had always mounted my Windows partition automatically to /media/Windows. When I do the same thing in Xubuntu, it does mount it correctly, but it doesn't show the link to the partition on my desktop.

I now that I could just set a link to the directory, but that's just not suitable for me. I want to now why Xfce doesn't show additional automatically mounted partitions on my desktop just like in Ubuntu/Unity. The / system and not-auto-mounted partitions are shown as usual.

fstab entry:

```
/dev/sda3       /media/Windows ntfs    uid=1000,umask=0022     0       0
```

Comment: So you know a way to do what you want, but you're asking *why* the Xfce developer have made a certain design choice.  That's not really a good question for Ask Ubuntu.  Only the Xfce developer(s) in charge of this can really answer, although I suspect in the end it would just come down to "Xfce tries to be minimalistic"  -- that's why people like it.

Answer (score 1):

Xfce and Gnome are not the same desktop environment and do not always behave the same. When installing/using Ubuntu, you are using Unity with the Gnome desktop. When you install Xubuntu, Xfce does not function the same as gnome. The Xfce developers have not written a function to show those partitions mounted in /etc/fstab on the desktop. As a matter of fact, one of the tricks often used by those using Xfce is to add a drive or partition to /etc/fstab to prevent seeing it on the desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Issue the comamnd

```
ln -s /media/Windows ~/Desktop/
```

And you should have a directory link on your Desktop.